# how to insert datagridview rows to database if the checkbox is checked

Tags: c#

I have a datagridview that contains:

worker_id

worker name

numberOfHours

AmountToPay

Paied?(checkbox column)

There is a button called save. when i click that button i want to go to each row in datagrid and check if the user checked the checkbox for that row or not. if the user checked it: insert that row data into the database and if not go to  the other row.

I don't have any problem with the queries, but how can i get the data corresponding to the checked boxes

i have this code for save button:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in PayingDG.Rows)
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cbxcell = row.Cells[4] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

            if ((bool)cbxcell.Value == true )
            {
                //insert the data of the current row into the database
            }

        }

    }
```

the problem is that when the checkbox is not checked it has a null value so it gives an error System.NullReferenceException

Comment: Not enough information.  Using DataBinding it is trivially `myDataAdapter.Update(dt);` We have no idea what your data access methods look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example that might help you

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn CheckboxColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        CheckboxColumn.TrueValue = true;
        CheckboxColumn.FalseValue = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(CheckboxColumn);
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(4);
    }

    private void chkItems_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[0];
            if (chk.Value == chk.FalseValue || chk.Value == null)
            {
                chk.Value = chk.TrueValue;
            }
            else
            {
                chk.Value = chk.FalseValue;
            }
    enter code here
        }
        dataGridView1.EndEdit();
    }
}
```